# Deploying helloworld docker images to GKE with Pulumi

Tags: typescript, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

I'm trying to deploy a hello world container in kubernetes using Pulumi and GCP

Basically I just want this local helloworld container to be deployed in an existing k8s cluster on GCP made following [this tutorial](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/tutorials/gcp/gcp-ts-gke-hello-world/).

Deploying local images is what is done in [this other example](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/crosswalk/kubernetes/apps/), however I need to add registry information which causes an error: `Property 'repositoryUrl' does not exist on type 'Promise<GetRegistryRepositoryResult>'.`

```
const registry = gcp.container.getRegistryRepository();
// Build a Docker image from a local Dockerfile context in the
// './mydockerimg' directory, and push it to the registry.
//const registry = gcp.container.getRegistryRepository();
const customImage = "mydockerimg";
const appImage = new docker.Image(customImage, {
//    imageName: pulumi.interpolate`${registry.repositoryUrl}/${customImage}:v1.0.0`,
    imageName: "mydockerimg",
    build: {
        context: `./${customImage}`,
    },
});
// Create a k8s provider.
// NOT NEEDED
// Create a Deployment of the built container.
const appLabels_helloworld = { app: customImage };
const appDeployment = new k8s.apps.v1.Deployment("app", {
    spec: {
        selector: { matchLabels: appLabels_helloworld },
        replicas: 1,
        template: {
            metadata: { labels: appLabels_helloworld },
            spec: {
                containers: [{
                    name: customImage,
                    image: appImage.imageName,
                    ports: [{name: "http", containerPort: 80}],
                }],
            }
        },
    }
}, { provider: clusterProvider });
```

When I just use `imageName: "mydockerimg",` rather than a registry, pulumi accepts the upgrade, but then I have a docker push error:

```
error: Error: ' docker push mydockerimg:4aff09801cccc271a8182a3eb3bc46a25764fdbb5332230c6aa707e3b90c4d4e' failed with exit code 1
    The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/mydockerimg]
```

Any help?

---

**EDIT:** After applying Yaron Idan's suggestion below, `pulumi up` is working, but still not exporting the app, being unable to push.

```
const gcrLocation = registry.then(registry => registry.repositoryUrl);
...
imageName: pulumi.interpolate`${gcrLocation}/${customImage}:v1.0.0`,
...
export const appDeploymentName = appDeployment.metadata.apply(m => m.name);
```

The error:

```
 Error: ' docker push gcr.io/XXX' failed with exit code 1
```

After some more investigation I have
error: name unknown: Buckets(projectID,artifacts.napoleongamesassignment.appspot.com)

after trying to `docker push gcr.io/myprojectID/myrstudio:latest`,

created [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431077/docker-push-to-google-cloud-gcp-fails-with-name-unknown-buckets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to extract the repository URL from the promise instead of it's resolution.
Going by this [example](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/gcp/container/getregistryrepository/) from the Pulumi docs, it looks like changing your code from

```
imageName: pulumi.interpolate`${registry.repositoryUrl}/${customImage}:v1.0.0`,
```

to

```
imageName: pulumi.interpolate`${registry.then(foo => foo.repositoryUrl)}/${customImage}:v1.0.0`,
```

Might give you the results you're looking for.

Comment: much appreciated. I still have an error, could you please check out the edits?