# docker push to google cloud GCP fails with name unknown: Buckets

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

Trying to push a local image to a google cloud project, which fails with this error. Any help?

```
$ docker push gcr.io/myprojectID/myrstudio:latest
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/ myprojectID  /myrstudio]
07fc541c7837: Preparing
5f40edd3a036: Preparing
8243f7003c86: Preparing
55903d33bbd7: Preparing
6f15325cc380: Preparing
1e77dd81f9fa: Preparing
030309cad0ba: Preparing
1e77dd81f9fa: Waiting
030309cad0ba: Waiting
6f15325cc380: Layer already exists
1e77dd81f9fa: Layer already exists
030309cad0ba: Layer already exists
55903d33bbd7: Pushed
07fc541c7837: Pushed
5f40edd3a036: Pushed
8243f7003c86: Pushed
name unknown: Buckets(myprojectID  ,artifacts. myprojectID.appspot.com)
```

Looks like something was pushed, but at some point failing...

EDIT: running wind 10 version 20H2 (OS build 19042.1288)

Comment: Please update your question with more details if possible (your setup, OS version you're running this on), did you tried on other computers/VM's etc.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions - https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling? Specifically the part about the required permissions for completing this task?

Comment: No news. Yes i did follow these steps, and i can see that some files are uploading, it's only after that i get this weird Buckets error... I'm on Windows.

Comment: Are you able to push other images or have issue with just this one ? 
Which version of Windows you're running ?

Comment: Hi @Wicktor, running wind 10 version 20H2 (OS build 19042.1288)

Answer (score 1):

When you perform a `docker push` to Google Container Registry your image is stored inside a bucket in your project;

> Container Registry uses Cloud Storage buckets as the underlying storage for container images. You control access to your images by granting permissions to the bucket for a registry.

**If this is a first time that you try to push an image - the account you're using must have [Storage Admin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) role. That's because a bucket that will store your images has to be created.**

Have a look at the [documentation that describes all the steps](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#grant) to grant necessary permissions.

If you're not familiar with GCP Cloud Storage then have a look at the guide describing [how to use GCP's storage buckets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#activating_a_cloud_storage_bucket).

Also you may consider [trying out Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr) which gives you more control over your images.

Comment: same error after performing the steps mentioned, including adding Storage Admin role. I do see some files within the buckets, so it should not be an authorization problem

Comment: I have the same error from 2 different computers by the way. pushing images correctly, then "name unknown"

Comment: these answers are the worst. No snippet, links to documentation that is built on weak assumptions or back-ups