# Docker push to GCP registry fails due to "uknown buckets"

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to push my own docker image to the GCP registry but when I do that I get the following output:

```
docker push gcr.io/<my-project-id>/<image>
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/<my-project-id>/<image>]
f15150e56202: Pushed
f4d9210559a2: Pushed
740ec60a06f1: Pushed
5f70bf18a086: Layer already exists
707ca84b07d6: Pushed
cd120726f64b: Layer already exists
033eaa4a923c: Layer already exists
3f6108380787: Layer already exists
1f8751be0506: Layer already exists
59b0c7a2fe4d: Layer already exists
7372faf8e603: Layer already exists
9be7f4e74e71: Layer already exists
36cd374265f4: Layer already exists
5bdeef4a08f3: Layer already exists
name unknown: Buckets(<my-project-id>,artifacts.<my-project-id>.appspot.com)
```

This is the same behaviour as the one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431077/docker-push-to-google-cloud-gcp-fails-with-name-unknown-buckets).

The bucket `artifacts.<my-project-id>.appspot.com` is created, and some stuff is pushed to it, so there is no access problem. It just seems that the docker push suddenly does not recognize the bucket.

I already double checked that I have all the permissions I need on my service account, I am logged in in my gcloud CLI and that docker is configured to use the gcp auth.

Any clues on why this might happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating the GCP project seems to have fixed this issue.